# How to get input from file piped to stdin

Tags: c++, command-line, arguments, command, cin

So, I have a program that I am running through a command line on a raspberry pi on C++. I know how I can pass in the command line arguments already, but I need to pass it using cin, but I'm not able to get it to work.

Normally I would use args, and use a format on the command line such as ./program filename, but I have to use this format `./program < filename` to redirect the filename to the program through stdin for this assignment. My instructor has told me to use cin, but no matter what I do, it will not open the file.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "Matching Brackets: NAME" << endl;
    string line;
    string fname;
    cin >> fname;

    ifstream myfile; 
    myfile.open(fname);

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        while ( getline (myfile,line) )
        {
            int num = valid(line);
            if(num >= 0)
            cout << valid(line) << " ";
        }
    }

    cout << endl;
    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to get the cin to take the actual filename of a text file and use that in fstream to open the file and read through it to perform the operations, but I can't get it to open in that method, and I haven't been able to find anything about doing it that way.

Answer (score 1):

When you use your program as

```
./program < filename
```

you only need to worry about reading content from `stdin/std::cin`. 
`main` can be simplified to:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   cout << "Matching Brackets: NAME" << endl;
   string line;

   while ( getline (std::cin, line) )
   {
      int num = valid(line);
      if(num >= 0)
         cout << num << " "; // No need to call valid(line) again;
   }

   cout << endl;
   return 0;
}
```